# Can we use "Jill has got hers" here?

Tags: phrases, informal-language

- Hey have you got an eraser?

- No I don't. But Jill has got hers. Ask her.

I know that we can use one instead of hers, but can we use hers as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's perfectly fine. Of course, it presupposes that the other person knows that Jill has an eraser.

> — Have you got my ticket?
>
>  — Nope, I've only got mine.

> — Have you got any advice for me?
>
>  — No, but ask Samir for his.